# Display in search tools with white space

Tags: javascript, html

I added a search tool for my Html page **(FAQ question)** using javascript. The code is working but the problem is that the result of the search appears in order. I mean if the following question doesn't match with the text in search there is an empty space, I used for that:

> **li[i].style.display = "none";**

But the white space isn't removed

[image: Search tools white space]

HTML code:

```
<div class="faq-content" id="faq-content">

<div class="faq-question" id="faq-question">
<input id="q1" type="checkbox" class="panel">
<div class="plus"><label for="q1" class="panel-title">+</label></div>
<label for="q1" class="panel-title" id="panel-title">What is your objective?</label>
<div class="panel-content">An objective is a short statement that clarifies your goals regarding the type of employment desired and how your skills make you a good fit.</div>
 </div>

Same code for all the questions


</div>
```

Javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, f;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("faq-content");
var element = ul.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (f = 0; f < element.length; f++) {
element[f].style.borderBottom= "none";}
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
        li[i].style.display = "";

    } 

   else {
       li[i].style.display = "none";


    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: i want to clear the vertical space in case there is only one result for the search (if in the list of faq, a question that didn't match the result I will receive an empty space instead of displaying the second result .. so the display is empty white space for each unmatch between the search and the question